# How set value in column according to another dataframe column's value

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have two DataFrames:

First: **df1**

```
df1 = {'NAME': ['A','B','C','D'],
        'GROUP': ['A1','B1','C1','D1']
        }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['NAME','GROUP'])

   NAME GROUP
0   A   A1
1   B   B1
2   C   C1
3   D   D1
```

Second: **df2**

```
df2 = {'NAME': ['AA','AAA','AAAA','BB','BBB','BBBB','CC','CCC','CCCC','DD','DDD','DDDD'],
        'GROUP': ['','','','','','','','','','','','']
        }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2,columns=['NAME','GROUP'])

    NAME    GROUP
0   AA  
1   AAA 
2   AAAA    
3   BB  
4   BBB 
5   BBBB    
6   CC  
7   CCC 
8   CCCC    
9   DD  
10  DDD 
11  DDDD
```

My task is set GROUP in df2 according the NAME in df1.

I think I need to use **contains** :
IF df1['NAME'] is in df2['NAME'] set GROUP to that in df1['NAME]. I tried to use a loop and convert the DataFrame into **arrays**, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Series.str.extract` to create the matching column you can merge on. Then bring the group over. Remove the `'GROUP'` column that already exists before the merge, and I left the `'match'` column in for clarity.

In the case of multiple substring matches, because this uses `.str.extract` it will merge with only the first substring match. (Multple matches can be handled with `.str.extractall` and some groupby to combine everything into, say, a list.)

```
pat = '(' + '|'.join(df1['NAME']) +')'
df2['match'] = df2['NAME'].str.extract(pat)

df2 = df2.drop(columns='GROUP').merge(df1.rename(columns={'NAME': 'match'}), how='left')
```

---

```
print(df2)

    NAME match GROUP
0     AA     A    A1
1    AAA     A    A1
2   AAAA     A    A1
3     BB     B    B1
4    BBB     B    B1
5   BBBB     B    B1
6     CC     C    C1
7    CCC     C    C1
8   CCCC     C    C1
9     DD     D    D1
10   DDD     D    D1
11  DDDD     D    D1
```