# create a new column with pandas using two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`  for example:

df1:

```
 Account          Type
0 a              Green
1 a              Red  
2 a              Gala 
3 a              orange
```

df2:

```
  Account         Type
0 a             Green apple
1 a             Red  apple
2 a             Gala apple
```

What I need to do is to create a column in `df1` called Type_2 where I will find the corresponded name for each type in df1 found in `df2`. In short, scan the whole array and get the result.

```
   Account      Type     Type_2
    0 a         Green   Green apple
    1 a         Red     Red apple
    2 a         Gala    Gala apple
    3 a         orange     Null
```

I am trying to learn, hope you can help me

Comment: Eh that dup isn't sufficiently focused enough for this problem. Use my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568862/how-set-value-in-column-according-to-another-dataframe-columns-value. You'll first need to use `.str.extract` to generate the exact keys you can then merge on (using that dup), though IMO the first part is the more difficult aspect

Comment: I think the idea is in this way. However, I am not clear about how to call the pat thing in my case.